# I can't get Safari to connect to localhost server on my Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP and had to change a few things in the configure files to, finally, get MYSQL Database to run. However, I can't get any of my files to open in Safari by using localhost. I'm only able to get index.html to open by looking for it in Finder. I also can't get access to phpMyAdmin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Northbank.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Northbank Database</h1>
            <img src="logo.png">
        </header>

        <nav>

        </nav>
        <main>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <?php
                
                    ?>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the basic code that all of the php pages currently have, using local host I should be able to view them by entering their name into the browser bar.

Comment: If you're not getting any response from http://localhost then Apache's probably not running. Your not giving us much (anything) to go on. Do you get an error when trying to start Apache from the XAMPP control panel?

Comment: No, Apache is running fine in the control panel

Comment: What does `sudo lsof -i :80` tell you? Have you checked the Apache logs? What error do you get when attempting to go to http://localhost/ Is there a servable file (index.html) in the DocumentRoot (possibly /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs)?